# Can I view what app data has not been uploaded to iCloud?

Tags: ios, backup, icloud

Viewing System Preferences -> iCloud on my Mac shows that I have 2.24GB out of the standard 5GB available, but each morning when I wake up I see an error message on my iPhone that 'There is not enough space to back up to iCloud'. I'm certain I had not added over 2GB of data to be backed up in a single day (the day this problem began).

When I go to Preferences -> General -> Usage on my iPhone, and tap 'Manage Storage', I see my three devices that have been bound to my Apple ID with backed up data, and the sizes (1.6GB, 633.6MB, 498.5MB) total the 2.7GB that the 'Backups' section lists. Underneath, app Documents & Data only total 651KB.

How do I know what it's trying to upload to iCloud? I don't want to go deleting data I'd rather save just to get it to backup appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Manage Storage` screen is one of those "live updating" screens like much of iOS' `Settings` section has. Like when iTunes Match rolled out, an iTunes Match login form simply appeared in the Music preferences. Or when you go into `General > Network`, how the "Set Up Personal Hotspot" only appears after apparently phoning home to your carrier to determine eligibility.

After going to `Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage` and waiting there for more than a few seconds, eventually the text as seen in this screenshot popped out and informed me of why backups were not taking place.

[image: Usage > Manage Storage screen]

It's not exactly telling me what hasn't been backed up, per the question, but I'm actually fine with this, because I just wanted to see *how much* content was not backed up.

I would up deciding to delete a previous device's backup data, and that, along with shutting off camera roll backups (due to videos), freed up enough space for backups to begin working again.

Hooray!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going to Preferences -> General -> Usage, go to Preferences -> **iCloud** -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage.

This screen will list your devices and by selecting the current device (like your iPhone if you're looking at it on your iPhone) you can see the list of applications that saves data to the backup. Here you can see the **backup size per app** and you can also **disable/enable them individually**.
To modify the settings for your other devices you need to go to the same screen on them.

Comment: I mentioned this in the second paragraph of my question. The totals in that area do not exceed 5GB, thus they are a current snapshot of iCloud usage which do not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer put me in the place I needed to be, even though the answer itself is not exactly correct.